# rc scripts dependencies

Tags: ubuntu, boot, linux

On a Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS server install certain services fail to start properly after a reboot.

I have a couple of virtual interfaces defined on eth0:

/etc/network/interfaces

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 172.16.5.240
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 172.16.5.1

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
    address 172.16.5.241
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 172.16.5.1

auto eth0:2
iface eth0:2 inet static
    address 172.16.5.242
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 172.16.5.1

auto eth0:3
iface eth0:3 inet static
    address 172.16.5.243
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 172.16.5.1
```

and so on...

Some SysV init scripts that try to bind to for example 172.16.5.243 fail during boot, complaining that there is no such IP address.

My questions:

1) Are the services started parallel by default? Can I disable that so they run sequentially?

2) Is there a way to define dependencies between rc scripts? I'm only familiar with the defining the order of seqentially started scripts using the numbers in /etc/rc[0-6].d/)

Any other fix or workaround appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no clear answer to your question. It depends whether the service which needs 172.16.5.243 is a SysV init script or a upstart job.

When it is a SysV init script, you can add dependencies with this header in the init script:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          scriptname
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO
```

When it is an Upstart script, take a look at [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/117584/upstart-scripts-run-a-task-after-networking-goes-up). The interesting part is in the accepted answer:

```
start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
```

Comment: They are SysV init scripts, depending on $network in Required-Start. Who provides $network? /etc/init.d/networking provides "networking".

Comment: You could also change `Required-Start $network` to `Required-Start $networking`. Or perhaps there is an update which corrects this.

Comment: The system is updated to the current state of 10.4 LTS. Loads of other system scripts use network instead of networking. Are you sure this is a bug?

Comment: No I'm not. This was just a possibility.