# Upstart job (haproxy)

Tags: haproxy, upstart

I am starting HA proxy using the following command:
**sudo etc/init.d/haproxy start**
and I stop HA proxy using:
**sudo etc/init.d/haproxy stop**
How can I write a basic upstart script for sudo etc/init.d/something start or stop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably reference the upstart documentation [here](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/) - this example is based off one of the answers given for [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/117584/upstart-scripts-run-a-task-after-networking-goes-up), adapting the other answers there nmay work as well.  The example below should start haproxy without a PID, then have it running in the background.

```
respawn
console none

start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE!=lo)
stop on [!12345]


pre-start exec etc/init.d/haproxy start
pre-stop  etc/init.d/haproxy stop
```

Answer (score 1):

I set it to start on boot, and then monitor with monit (http://mmonit.com/monit/).  Haven't used upstart, but this works very well for me.  :)